# how to put a bind-value and an onchange in the same input checkbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

hello community I have a problem putting a `bind-value` and an `onchange` shows me the following error:

```
The attribute 'onchange' is used two or more times for this element. Attributes must be unique (case-insensitive). The attribute 'onchange' is used by the '@bind' directive attribute.
```

this is my `input checkbox`:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1"
       @bind-value="@ProveedorEstadoCarrito.Cotizacion.Aceptada"
       @onchange="e => CheckChanged(e)">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Aceptada</label>
 </div>
</div>
```

this is the event:

```
private Boolean Aceptada = false;
private async Task CheckChanged(ChangeEventArgs ev)
{
    Aceptada = (Boolean)ev.Value;
    ProveedorEstadoCarrito.Cotizacion.Aceptada = Aceptada;       
    if (Aceptada == true)
    {
        var httpResponse = await repositorio.Put("api/Cotizacion", ProveedorEstadoCarrito.Cotizacion);
        if (httpResponse.Error)
        {
            await mostrarMensajes.MostrarMensajeError(await httpResponse.GetBody());
        }
        else
        {
            navigationManager.NavigateTo("/formulario-cotizacion");
        }
    }
}
```

I want the checkbox to be activated with the `bind` if it was clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you usually don't bind to the value attribute. It remains fixed, and when present, and within a form element, it is passed as form data to the server.

What you want is the checked attribute, like the code snippet below demonstrates:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="@selected" 
       @onchange="@((args) => selected = (bool) args.Value)" /> 

@code {
    private bool selected;
}
```

The above code show how to bind to a check box element. As you can see, the above code creates a two-way data binding, from a variable to the element, and from the element to the variable. The value attribute is involved. The same usage is applicable to the radion button element. Unlike other input elements, both employ the checked attribute, not the value attribute.

You may also use this variation:

```
<input type="checkbox" @bind="selected" />
```

which is equivalent to the code above: a checked attribute + onchange event, but the version above can let you solve your issue. Here's how your code may look like:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1" checked="@ProveedorEstadoCarrito.Cotizacion.Aceptada" @onchange="CheckChanged">
```

And

```
private async Task CheckChanged(ChangeEventArgs ev)
{
    Aceptada = (Boolean)ev.Value;
    ProveedorEstadoCarrito.Cotizacion.Aceptada = Aceptada;       
    if (Aceptada == true)
    {
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But you can set `checked=ProveedorEstadoCarrito.Cotizacion.Aceptada` to update the state of the checkbox, and for the `@onchange` event do `@onchange=CheckChanged` and in that method you can set  `ProveedorEstadoCarrito.Cotizacion.Aceptada = (bool) ev.Value;`

Comment: if i do this  ProveedorEstadoCarrito.Cotizacion.Aceptada = (bool) ev.Value;  it no longer updates the value from false to true